# Why does water always take an already travelled path?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension

I asked this question because I want a 'physics' answer. Now let me clarify the question. Assume that we let a drop of water fall on a flat surface. It should theoretically stay still. Now let the surface be inclined at an angle. The water droplet now goes on a path. Now repeat the steps and the same path will be observed. Why?

Comment: A similar question was asked here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/456632/

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in the relationship of water with other molecules. Cohesive forces are the interactions between the like molecules, while the adhesive force signifies the interaction between unlike molecules. It seems like once the water establishes a path on a surface, the other drops follow the same path since cohesive forces (between water molecules) act stronger than adhesive forces (between water molecules and surface molecules). Water molecules need to spend higher surface energy to form a new way. To spend lesser energy, the subsequent drops travel on the same path.